# Is there a possibillity to show the 0 on an logarithmic scale with matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, math

I have to show the plot of a function with `matplotlib` in python with logarithmic scale on the x axis and I wonder if there is any possibility to show `x=0`? I'm aware that there is no `log(0)`...

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
def fkt(x,e):
    y=np.sin(1/(x+e))
    return y

def bild_fkt():
    """plottet die Funktion im Intervall[0,1] mit epsilon=1/5, 1/10, 1/20 mit linearer und 
    logarithmischer Skala """
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))       
    x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
    plt.subplot(211)   #plots on linear scale
    plt.plot(x, fkt(x,1/5), 'r', lw=2, label='e=1/5')
    plt.plot(x, fkt(x,1/10), '-.', color='b', label='e=1/10')
    plt.plot(x, fkt(x,1/20), ':', color='g', label='e=1/20')
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.grid()

    y=np.logspace(0,0.3010299957,100)   #plots on logarithmic scale
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(y-1, fkt(y-1,1/5), 'r', lw=2, label='e=1/5')
    plt.plot(y-1, fkt(y-1,1/10), '-.', color='b', label='e=1/10')
    plt.plot(y-1, fkt(y-1,1/20), ':', color='g', label='e=1/20')
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.grid()
    plt.semilogx()

bild_fkt()
```

Comment: What is the scale on the `y` axis? You say `f(x) = 0`, which seems to mean `y = 0`.

Comment: oh, you are right. on y-axis i'd like to use linear scale, on x-axis logarithmic scale. what i wanted to say is x=0

Comment: ```log(0)``` is undefined. So its not possible to plot that on a graph. Having ```0``` on an axis is  a different thing though.

Comment: Well, obviously not. As you go closer to `x = 0` on the `x-axis`, the values get smaller and smaller, tending to `0`, but never reaching it. On a linear scale, I consider the centre to be `0` and there are negative values to the left and positive to the right. On a log scale, I consider the centre to be `1` and fractional values to the left and multiples on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method
[`yscale`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html) (or `xscale` respectively):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dummy data
x = list(range(0,10))
y = [10**i for i in x]

# open figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
# plot linear scale
ax[0].plot(x,y)
# plot logarithmic scale (two options
ax[1].plot(x,y)
plt.yscale("log")
#ax[1].set_yscale("log")
```

[image: linear vs logarithmic scale image]

Note that I have used two different options to set the scale. The first is the function `plt.yscale("log")` that uses the current active axis. The second (out-commented) way is to use `set_yscale` as a method of the *AxesSubplot*-object.